# gettting this error when i try to run eclipse in ubuntu please help

Tags: eclipse

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @48a242ce
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.findAddURLMethod(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller.<clinit>(FrameworkExtensionInstaller.java:36)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Eclipse or have you been using it for a while and it just stopped working?  What method did you use for installing Eclipse?  What is the version of Eclipse that you are running?  Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  Which version of JDK did you install?

Comment: yes it is a new installation never used it before, i downloaded it from the official website of eclipse it's Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3) ,i tried installing it manually but gave error "An error occurred.See the log file" i don't know where to see the log file,and then i tried running it from terminal that was the error above, i'm using ubuntu 17.04 and my jdk version is 9 - @L.D.James

Comment: The download from the official site (normally) isn't an install.  It's a packaged standalong application that can be run from where you opened the package.  What is the exact command you used for starting it?

Comment: i extracted the folder and ran ' ./eclipse-inst ' in terminal ,the eclipse installer window pops up and goes followed by error window "An error occurred.See the log file"

Comment: What is the output of these two commands: **1)** `java -version`; **2)** `javac -version`

Comment: java -version = 
openjdk version "9-Ubuntu", 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b161-1),
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b161-1, mixed mode),
__2) javac -version = 
javac 9-Ubuntu

Comment: I'm trying to get some clarification of where you are with Eclipse.  Your question indicates that you have problems after having installed Eclipse.  However, you are giving an install step for your attempt to run Eclipse.  The step you presented is the install process.  If you got that error at that step, Eclipse isn't installed.  Can you verify if I'm correct that you haven't installed Eclipses yet? The remedy will depend on if Eclipse has been installed, or if it's not installed and you are trying to install it.

Comment: im trying to install it freshly i have recently switched to ubuntu so this is my first installation of eclipse, anyways that solution worked thanks @L.D.James

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment... glad it working and resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is your JDK installed version.  Version 9 isn't totally compatible with a number of Java applications.  Most applications that are optimized for Version 9 have downward compatibility to at leave version 8.

You can resolve this installation issue by installing Java version 8 (which is the default version for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 17.X.

**Install the default Java JDK version with this command:**

```
$ sudo apt install default-jdk
```

**Then switch to the version 8 default with this command:'**

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Now your Eclipse installation should proceed without problems.  You'll also be able to run the installed without problems.

From time to time if you want to test the compatibility of the version 9, you can use the `update-alternatives --config java` command above to switch between versions.

**Note:**

**For your information**, once installed Eclipse will work with Java version 9.  The problem with the version is a glitch in the installer.  So it may not matter much which version you enable once you have installed the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall Java and Eclipse. Then first install Java and Eclipse after it. It will work.